# How do I get elements to re-appear after closing? (jquery)

Tags: jquery, image, toggle, gallery

So for my portfolio I have a gallery of thumbnails, and when you click on the thumbnail you get a full-screen preview. I also set my code so that when you click on an image, the 'menu' button disappears as well as the thumbnail gallery. 
The elements disappear when I click an image, but when I exit the full screen preview the elements don't re-appear, they remain gone.

My js:

```js
$('.gallery ul li a').click(function() {
  var itemID = $(this).attr('href');
  $('.gallery ul').addClass('item_open');
  $(itemID).addClass('item_open');
  return false;
});

$('.close').click(function() {
  $('.port, .gallery ul').removeClass('item_open');
  return false;
});

$(".gallery ul li a").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: parseInt($("#top").offset().top)
  }, 400);
  //ELEMENTS THAT I'M HIDING WHEN I CLICK A GALLERY THUMBNAIL//
  $(".gallery").hide();
  $(".burger").hide();
  $(".close").show();
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  clear: both;
}
.row img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  // z-index: 1000;
  position: static;
}
.gallery ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0.87719%;
}
.gallery {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 60px;
}
.gallery ul {
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.gallery ul li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 23.24561%;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
.gallery ul li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
.gallery ul li a:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -14px 0 0 -16px;
  background: url('http://i58.tinypic.com/aowbw8.png') no-repeat;
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.gallery ul li a:hover:before {
  top: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}
.gallery ul li a:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.gallery ul li a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.port {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  z-index: 1000;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.port img {
  width: 50%;
}
.port .description {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 0 40px 40px;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: 'lato';
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.port h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #fbe2d4;
  background: url("http://www.julie-lavergne.com/img/common/trame.png");
  padding: 15px;
}
.port > * {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.port.item_open {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  transform: translateY(0%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.port > * {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.close {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url("http://i57.tinypic.com/6e15lj.png") no-repeat center;
  left: 2%;
  top: 10%;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  content: 'close';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="gallery">

  <div class="row">
    <ul>

      <li>
        <a href="#item02">
          <img src="http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/113500-Pretty-Seashells.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#item02">
          <img src="http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/113500-Pretty-Seashells.jpg" alt="">
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#item02">
          <img src="http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/113500-Pretty-Seashells.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="image" href="#item01">
          <img src="http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/113500-Pretty-Seashells.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="image" href="#item02">
          <img src="http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/113500-Pretty-Seashells.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="image" href="#item01">
          <img src="http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/113500-Pretty-Seashells.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="image" href="#item01">
          <img src="http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/113500-Pretty-Seashells.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="image" href="#item01">
          <img src="http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/113500-Pretty-Seashells.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- / row -->

</section>
</div>

<!-- Item 01 -->
<div id="item01" class="port">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="description">

      <h1>Item 01</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus quis libero erat. Integer ac purus est. Proin erat mi, pulvinar ut magna eget, consectetur auctor turpis.</p>
    </div>

    <img src="http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/113500-Pretty-Seashells.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- / row -->

</div>
<!-- / Item 02 -->

<!-- Item 02 -->
<div id="item02" class="port">


  <div class="row">
    <div class="description">
      <h1>Item 02</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus quis libero erat. Integer ac purus est. Proin erat mi, pulvinar ut magna eget, consectetur auctor turpis.</p>
    </div>
    <img src="http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/113500-Pretty-Seashells.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="close"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- / row -->

</div>
<!-- / Item 02 -->
```

How do I make .gallery and .burger appear back again when I close the window? Thank you!

Comment: Please share jsfiddle

Comment: Your close button never does `$(".gallery, .burger").show()`

Comment: Where is the code for clicking on an image? You have two handlers for clicking on `.gallery ul li a`, which I guess is the thumbnail.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xqkv6gb9/ - its not really working here though. like the background is suppose to dissapear when you click. the "x" icon is in white so you can't see it. @Barmar the second but of code is the one that is removing the background. when I apply it to first set it won't work. thanks!

Comment: There's no `id="top"`, so it's getting an error when it tries to do `$("#top").offset().top`. The rest of the code in that function is skipped, so it doesn't hide the gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.close` click handler needs to show the elements that were hidden when you clicked on the thumbnail.

```js
$('.gallery ul li a').click(function() {
  var itemID = $(this).attr('href');
  $('.gallery ul').addClass('item_open');
  $(itemID).addClass('item_open');
  return false;
});

$('.close').click(function() {
  $('.port, .gallery ul').removeClass('item_open');
  // Show the elements that were hidden when clicking on the thumbnail
  $('.gallery, .burger').show();
  $('.close').hide();
  return false;
});

$(".gallery ul li a").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: parseInt($("#top").offset().top)
  }, 400);
  //ELEMENTS THAT I'M HIDING WHEN I CLICK A GALLERY THUMBNAIL//
  $(".gallery").hide();
  $(".burger").hide();
  $(".close").show();
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  clear: both;
}
.row img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  // z-index: 1000;
  position: static;
}
.gallery ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0.87719%;
}
.gallery {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 60px;
}
.gallery ul {
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.gallery ul li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 23.24561%;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
.gallery ul li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
.gallery ul li a:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -14px 0 0 -16px;
  background: url('http://i58.tinypic.com/aowbw8.png') no-repeat;
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.gallery ul li a:hover:before {
  top: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}
.gallery ul li a:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.gallery ul li a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.port {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  z-index: 1000;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.port img {
  width: 50%;
}
.port .description {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 0 40px 40px;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: 'lato';
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.port h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #fbe2d4;
  background: url("http://www.julie-lavergne.com/img/common/trame.png");
  padding: 15px;
}
.port > * {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.port.item_open {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  transform: translateY(0%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.port > * {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.close {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url("http://i57.tinypic.com/6e15lj.png") no-repeat center;
  left: 2%;
  top: 10%;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  content: 'close';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="gallery">

  <div class="row">
    <ul>

      <li>
        <a href="#item02">
          <img src="http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/113500-Pretty-Seashells.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#item02">
          <img src="http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/113500-Pretty-Seashells.jpg" alt="">
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#item02">
          <img src="http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/113500-Pretty-Seashells.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="image" href="#item01">
          <img src="http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/113500-Pretty-Seashells.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="image" href="#item02">
          <img src="http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/113500-Pretty-Seashells.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="image" href="#item01">
          <img src="http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/113500-Pretty-Seashells.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="image" href="#item01">
          <img src="http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/113500-Pretty-Seashells.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="image" href="#item01">
          <img src="http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/113500-Pretty-Seashells.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- / row -->

</section>
</div>

<!-- Item 01 -->
<div id="item01" class="port">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="description">

      <h1>Item 01</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus quis libero erat. Integer ac purus est. Proin erat mi, pulvinar ut magna eget, consectetur auctor turpis.</p>
    </div>

    <img src="http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/113500-Pretty-Seashells.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- / row -->

</div>
<!-- / Item 02 -->

<!-- Item 02 -->
<div id="item02" class="port">


  <div class="row">
    <div class="description">
      <h1>Item 02</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus quis libero erat. Integer ac purus est. Proin erat mi, pulvinar ut magna eget, consectetur auctor turpis.</p>
    </div>
    <img src="http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/113500-Pretty-Seashells.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="close"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- / row -->

</div>
<!-- / Item 02 -->
```

Comment: also quick question - how do i get rid of the animate when i close it? it slides up the screen. i just want it to simply exit and show the gallery again. possible? thanks!!

Comment: Not sure. I think that has to do with the transitions in your CSS, and I'm not very expert in that.